# How to specify multiple alternative Download-URLs for dynamic bundle JRE

Tags: install4j

Is it possible to configure the generated `install4j setup-program` in such a way that it tries two different URLs, one after the other, to download a dynamically bundled JRE?

In my use-case, I would need a behavior that if the download from the first URL failed (because the host is not reachable, for example) it would try the second URL?

I've found an advice in the documentation saying:

> [...] Adding an FTP download URL will increase the chance that the download will work on Unix-like systems behind restrictive firewalls.

So it sounds a little bit as if it is possible to add another URL (FTP in this case).

How can I add such a second URL and could it also be a `HTTP URL`?

Answer (score 0):

As of install4j 7.x, no fallback HTTP URLs can be configured.